# Metadata navigation removing views

Tags: list-view, view, metadata

By default SharePoint will show the first 3 views in a library and allow you to see more by click the ellipses "...", but for some reason my library is only showing the first view and then giving me the ellipses. It was working great until someone edited one of the views, and now it won't go back to the default of 3 views unless I remove metadata navigation.

Has anyone come across this before?

I am using SharePoint Enterprise 2013

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. Simply going into the library settings and clicking on "per-location view settings" will do this. Even if you click on it and then click cancel. I have not found a way to reverse this.